# How to add global exception handling to a add-in dll?

Tags: .net, wpf, exception, error-handling, wpf-controls

Here's my context:

- I am writing a WPF add-in for an application.
- This Application's main thread is unmanaged.
- I want to add a global exception handling system for this add-in to handle any unhandled exceptions.

Here's what I've tried but not working:

- I cannot add a try-catch block to my Application.Run() code line. Because I am an add-in, that code fragment is in the application.
- System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException is not working too. There might not be an WinForm Application exists. (WPF hosting in unmanaged code.)
- AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException is not working too. Because maybe it's handled by the Application itself. It just doesn't enter my code.

---

So, any ideas for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't touch global exception handling even if you could, you are writing an add-in and hooking into global exception handling will change not just the behavior of your add-in but also the main application and every other add-in in the system - doing something that may introduce bugs into other add-ins is not being a good neighbor :-)

Now, what you can do it wrap every externally callable method in your add-in with a try-catch block, this is obviously unmaintainable but an AOP system like PostSharp can easily add those for you while keeping the handling code in a nice central location.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right, I shouldn't add a global exception handling for this application. But is there any way to add a "global" exception handling system to only my add-in region - only the exceptions which thrown by my add-in would go to this system.

Add try-catch blocks only to my entries are not enough because I have a bunch of behaviors in my add-in's GUI..

Thank you very much for your point again.

Comment: You can use PostSharp to automatically add try-catch like behavior to all your code - even code in properties, converters, behaviors and user/custom controls - so that should cover most cases, I don't have a good solution for exceptions thrown by someone else's code inside your GUI

Answer (score -1):

```
 Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
```